# LINQ equivalent of keyset based pagination in postgres

Tags: postgresql, linq, where-clause, timescaledb, keyset-pagination

I have a postgresql query that does pagination using a keyset-based approach.

```
SELECT *
FROM public.values_with_variable_view
WHERE ( timestamp, id) > ('2024-01-04 01:12:09.267335+00',1996)
ORDER BY ( timestamp, id) asc
LIMIT 100
```

I have a requirement to write this using LINQ in c#. I tried using the where clause with `.Where(x=>x.timestamp > '2024-01-04 01:12:09.267335+00' &&  x.id > 1996)`
but it gives a different result.

Here is [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mQ9VMWZn)

Comment: The tuple comparison is not a simple *AND*. I believe the equivalent would be `.Where(x=>(x.timestamp = '2023-11-30 09:32:19.776586' &&  x.id > 1) || x.timestamp > '2023-11-30 09:32:19.776586')` or possibly `.Where(x=>(x.timestamp >= '2023-11-30 09:32:19.776586' &&  (x.timestamp > '2023-11-30 09:32:19.776586' || x.id > 1))`. I expect the latter would be more efficient, since the first part of that comparison before the `&&` is *sargable*.

Comment: An equivalent LINQ condition might be `.Where(x=>new { x.timestamp, x.id } > new { prior.timestamp,  prior.id })`, but I am not sure if `>` works with anonymous types or if you data provider can map it to the equivalent postgres SQL.

Comment: .Where(x=>new { x.timestamp, x.id } > new { prior.timestamp,  prior.id }) Not seems to be working

Comment: this link has the proposed implementation https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26822

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `||` part:

```cs
var query = context.values_with_variable_view
    .Where(x => x.timestamp > '2023-11-30 09:32:19.776586' 
        || x.timestamp == '2023-11-30 09:32:19.776586' && x.id > 1)
    .OrderBy(x => x.timestamp)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
    .Take(100);
```

Comment: This not seems to be working, have added DBFiddle, can you please look at it once.

Comment: Because you have not applied my code: `where timestamp > '2024-01-04 01:12:09.267335+00'
  or timestamp = '2024-01-04 01:12:09.267335+00'
  and 
  id > 1996`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the `.Where(x => x.timestamp >= last.timestamp && (x.timestamp > last.timestamp || x.id > last.id))` form for potentially better performance.  Having the `x.timestamp >= last.timestamp` condition up front with no alternative ***or*** condition should promote better index usage. The second part of the condition refines the filter after the initial index seek.

Combined with the code from Svyatoslav Danyliv's post, the answer would be:

```
var query = context.values_with_variable_view
    .Where(x =>
        x.timestamp >= last.timestamp                       // Index seek part
        && (x.timestamp > last.timestamp || x.id > last.id) // Filter part
    )
    .OrderBy(x => x.timestamp)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
    .Take(100);
```

See [this updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Fkbf26uN).

Note that I have added an index for `(timestamp, id)` on the test table.

The real determination as to which is best should be to try both options against live data (presumably substantially larger than 25 rows) and review the execution plans for performance.